# How to reduce gwt.create when using I18N in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I'm on a new and pretty big (but old) GWT project using I18N like that :

```
protected Messages i18n = GWT.create(Messages.class);
```

We have an abstract class that create the variable I18N and all screens are using it but only screens, not callback, popup etc.. so this results in more than 300 call to this GWT.create to make the i18n variable.

Is there any way to make this call more generic ? 
Does GWT.create use a lot of ressources ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Speed up compilation? Simplify code?

Comment: Simplify code at the very least, speeding up compilation would be great :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `GWT.create()` is no more than a call to a constructor at the very worst. Avoiding `new` for small objects in a GC'd language is usually not a big deal - usually.

However, these `Messages` implementations will be totally stateless, and with only one possible implementation (per permutation, and all bets are off if you compile all possible locales into the same permutation), so the compiler gets to be slightly clever here. In this case, it notices that there is only one implementation, and makes all methods static. Then, since there are no instance methods, there doesn't even need to be a constructor, so all of those calls to `GWT.create` (which were `new GeneratedMessagesImpl()` anyway) may end up being removed entirely)!

In short, don't worry about it - the `TextNode`s and `Element`s that are created that hold and render those strings are far more costly than a constructor of such a simple type would ever be, even without a compiler behind them.

Answer (score 2):

If you use UiBinder for views, you can inject resources into your view for use. There is no need to explicity call GWT.create for each Message class.

Example:

UiBinder XML file:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
   xmlns:gwt='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
   <ui:with type="com.example.i18n.Messages" field="mes"></ui:with>
   <gwt:HTMLPanel>

   </gwt:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Java View:

```
    public class ExampleUiView extends Composite {

    // ... fields

    @UiField
    Messages res; // field name must correspond to UiBinder.xml name

    }
```

Then you can use your res object being injected into View and XML skeleton.

Comment: Oh indeed, we're not using UiBinder at the moment but this looks like a neat way to do that :)

Comment: It is very useful, especially if you have a lot of Views.. Of course you don't have to pass reference from XML to view.. It is enough to use it in UiBinder XML like: <g:Label  text="{res.methodName}" /> and you avoid creating Message object and referencing it in view :-)

Comment: It is worth noting that no matter how you create the messages, `GWT.create` is always used to instantiate them, including uibinder, which is itself compiled to generated Java.